# How to convert WebElement to String or obtain String array?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I have a code that retrieves the URL's of a webpage. I wanted to know if it is possible to convert this to a String or obtain a String from the System.out.print() method?

```
    for(WebElement link : links)
       System.out.println(link.getAttribute("href"));
```

Edit1: I would like to create an array of strings obtained from the above code if it is possible.

I would like to copy the codes output information and use it in an email for only 15 items:

```
    for(int x = 1; x < 15 ; x++) {
       String url = link.getAttribute("href");
       messageBodyPart.setText(url);}
```

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're asking. link.getAttribute("href") already returns a String - what exactly do you need?

Comment: Trying to figure out how to use that output information to place in JavaMail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have an array list you can have it as:

```
List<String> urls = new ArrayList<String>();
for(WebElement link : links){
    urls.add(link.getAttribute("href"))
}
```

And then use it by fetching list elements in your java mail.

Comment: Ok thanks. I think this will work for what I intended.

Comment: It works and I got it to do exactly what I wanted afterwards, thank you so much.